# MpChartLib in Android - hide text in small slices of PieChart

Tags: pie-chart, mpandroidchart

How can i hide text of small slices in pie chart without to remove the text from the legend in the bottom?

I tried to remove the text like this:

```
    if ((yVal < 5F) {
        name = "";
    } else {
       //Add to y values
    }
```

But then the legent text is empty also. so the users can't really know who is this slice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to separate the legend texts and the pie chart slices text.
I set the legend (bottom map for each color) text and colors in this way
- In loop for all the contacts:

```
List<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();

labels.add(fullName);
colors.add(METRIC_COLORS[index]);

Legend l = chart.getLegend();
l.setCustom(colors, labels);
```

In addition I added the text of pie-slices:

```
PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yVals1, "");
dataSet.setColors(METRIC_COLORS);
```

Comment: And how did you check which slices are too small? From what I see here you simply do not display the labels in the chart.

Comment: I just tested it. and decided that below number (X) I won't display the labels. Check for 5%/2%/1%/0.5%

Comment: when did you do that? can you post some code samples? I have the same issue and I tried to loop through PieEntries but get value returns float instead of percentage...

Answer (score 0):

I have a situation like this:

```
for (PieEntry pieEntry : leastPieEntries){
            if(pieEntry.getValue() < 10)
            {
                pieEntry.setLabel("");
            }
        }
```

Tried to loop through all PieEntries but getValue returns the float value instead of percentage value...how did you do it?